# How to handle transaction locks in Java (Postgresql)

Tags: java, postgresql, transactions

I'm trying to come up with a solution for handling transaction locks and its recovery.

I have the following code like this:

```
try  {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
    Connection conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);


    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    conn2.setAutoCommit(false);

    conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ);
    conn2.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ);

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    Statement stmt2 = conn2.createStatement();

    stmt.setQueryTimeout(100);
    stmt.executeUpdate("update layout set HEIGHT = 45 where ID = 2");
    stmt2.setQueryTimeout(10);
    stmt2.executeUpdate("update layout set HEIGHT = 12 where ID = 2");
    conn2.commit();
    conn.commit();

    System.out.println("Done....");
}

//TODO: should be throwing it back..
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I'm updating `layout` table in two separate transactions. Now this will result in lock and hence I re-cover that situation using `setQueryTimeout`.

But I'm not really sure whether `setQueryTimeout` is the right way to handle the transaction locks and recover. Are there any other best practices?

Note that I'm not using any ORM's rather plain Java.

Comment: few theory, 'pessimistic locking' and 'optimistic locking' is known to You? Hard to say in general how to do 'recovery', because many scenarios and many requirements can exist. It is one of important questions in corporate software

Comment: Imagine bank or big internet shop, and You are client. What 'transaction recovery policy' should be designed?

Comment: @JacekCz: Sorry I'm not aware of this.

Comment: ok, dummy question - why you don't share the same connection for both updates?

Answer (score 0):

The Dbms will work with locks. You can increase or decrease the number by Optimistic or pessimistic locking, isolation level, mvcc,...
In the end locks will be used and possibly lead to deadlocks or long waiting periods. The most reasonable solution for this, I can think of, are timeouts.
Important is, how you recover from a timeout exception.

The recovery should be, that the transaction  should be retried after the Timeout. Normally this solves most cases. To make sure that you also can handle cases were the cause for the lock stays for a longer time you should decide about:

- the waiting time interval between retries, probably increasing
- the maximum number of retries
- the strategy, how to alarm if the problem can't be resolved by the system.